# How to replace string occur in NSMutableString from another string

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have a NSMutableString that contains a word twice.(e.g. /abc ...................... /abc).

Now I want to replace these two occurrences of /abc with /xyz. I want to replace only first and last occurence no other occurences.

```
 - (NSUInteger)replaceOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target
                               withString:(NSString *)replacement
                                  options:(NSStringCompareOptions)opts 
                                    range:(NSRange)searchRange
```

I find this instance method of NSMutableString but I am not able to use it in my case. 
Anyone have any solution??

Comment: Is this for a URL?  If so, there are a bunch of methods you can use in NSURL ("URLByDeletingLastPathComponent" for example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByDeletingLastPathComponent)

Comment: No,its not NSURL its just a NSMutableString.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first find the two ranges and then replace them seperately:

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"/abc asdfpjklwe /abc"];

NSRange a = [s rangeOfString:@"/abc"];
NSRange b = [s rangeOfString:@"/abc" options:NSBackwardsSearch];

if ((a.location == NSNotFound) || (b.location == NSNotFound))  {
    // at least one of the substrings not present
} else {
    [s replaceCharactersInRange:a withString:@"/xyz"];
    [s replaceCharactersInRange:b withString:@"/xyz"];
}
```

Comment: It gives exception - "range out of bound". When I check the value of a and b it gives some garbage value(22666222).

Comment: @Greshi: Remember to check for `NSNotFound`.